# passing array to other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have this code to passing array to other activity I need enter the number to int array from user and then pass it. how can do this?
first activity

```
public void onclick(){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
    i.putExtra("numbers", array);
    startActivity(i);
```

second activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int[] arrayB = extras.getIntArray("numbers");

     textView.setText( ":val:" +arrayB[1]);
    finish();
```

Comment: You can do this. What is the encountered problem?

Comment: and where is the problem? .... if `array` in first activity is `int[]` this should works ...

Comment: problem is I don't know how can do this how can receive the number by input from screen

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of int like below:

```
int [] arr = new int[] { 87, 65 };
```

And add Numbers that you take from user.
Next, create a Bundle object like `private Bundle bundle` and add your array into it.

```
bundle.putIntArray("foo", arr);
```

In Second Activity, you can read/fetch this value:

```
bundle.getIntArray("foo");
```

Comment: ,if I use this int [] arr = new int[] { 87, 65 }; when I run the App can I enter the number from screen ?! because u use { 87, 65 } this constant. how add Numbers that I take from user,sorry but I'm beginner in android

Comment: you can use edit text in Android to get input from user, convert that into integer and save it into `arr`

Comment: how can do this please if u can help